# FAA Aircraft Registration Form AC 8050-3 doesn't exist

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, aircraft-certification

I am preparing to certify a **self-built** aircraft as flightworthy and legal to fly, and was reading the required documents listed on FAA's [Amateur-Built Aircraft Airworthiness Certification page](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/gen_av/ultralights/amateur_built/aw/) when I realized that FAA does not have the required document "**AC Form 8050-3**" when searching the form on the [FAA Forms website](https://www.faa.gov/forms/). Is this some kind of mistake? Or is the form possibly a form located inside of a larger form, which could explain why it isn't showing up (Because if that were the case, it wouldn't be its own *individual* file)? If anyone could provide a link to this form, that would be great.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's because 8050-1 is the Aircraft Registration *Application*, and 8050-3 is the *Certificate* of Aircraft Registration.

You submit 8050-1, and the FAA sends you 8050-3.

Comment: Now you got me curious to what 8050-2 contains.

Comment: @Mast According to a short Google search, it's the "Aircraft Bill of Sale" to prove ownership of an aircraft.

Comment: @Mast UFO records.